# Proving that $f(x) = \ln x$ is continuous at $a = 3$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, analysis

Proving that $f(x) = ln x$ is continuous at $a = 3$.

The book wrote this solution:

> [image]

But when I started by $|f(x) - f(3)| < \varepsilon$ to find the appropriate $\delta$, I arrived at $ 3e^{-\varepsilon} -3 < x-3 < 3e^\varepsilon -3$, I do not understand why he take delta the minimum of the left hand side and right hand side of $x-3$, why he did not take directly that $\delta = 3e^\varepsilon -3$? could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: You get $e^{\varepsilon}$ by writing `e^{\varepsilon}`. You could also use `\epsilon` instead, but it doesn't look as nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\big|\ln x-\ln 3\big|=\big|\ln\left(\dfrac{x}{3}\right)\big|\lt\varepsilon$ whenever $-\varepsilon\lt\ln\left(\dfrac{x}{3}\right)\lt\varepsilon\implies e^{-\varepsilon}\lt\dfrac{x}{3}\lt e^{\varepsilon}\implies 3e^{-\varepsilon}\lt x\lt 3e^{\varepsilon}.$

Thus $\big|\ln x-\ln 3\big|\lt\varepsilon$  whenever $|x-3|\lt\delta$

where $\delta$=$\min(3-3e^{-\varepsilon},3e^{\varepsilon}-3).$

$\varepsilon\gt 0\implies e^{\varepsilon}\gt 1\implies \dfrac{1}{e^{\varepsilon}}\lt 1\implies \dfrac{e^{\varepsilon}-1}{e^{\varepsilon}}\lt e^{\varepsilon}-1\implies 1-e^{-\varepsilon}\lt e^{\varepsilon}-1\implies 3-3e^{-\varepsilon}\lt 3e^{\varepsilon}-3\implies \min(3-3e^{-\varepsilon},3e^{\varepsilon}-3)=3-3e^{-\varepsilon}.$

$\therefore \big|\ln x-\ln 3\big|\lt\varepsilon$  whenever $|x-3|\lt3e^{-\varepsilon}-3$

Hence $\ln x$ is continuous at $x=3$.

Comment: what is your choice of $\delta$?

Comment: $\delta$ is the radius of the open ball centered at 3 which contains all points for which the inequality $|\ln x-\ln 3|\lt \epsilon$ holds. Thus $\delta=min(3-3e^{-\epsilon},3e^{\epsilon}-3)$

Comment: and why we do not know which one is smaller than the other?

Comment: Here there are two open concentric balls-(i) centred at 3 with radius $3-3e^{-\epsilon}$ and (ii) centred at 3 with radius $3e^{\epsilon}-3$. We take the smaller one viz (ii)

Comment: which one is smaller?

Comment: $e^{\epsilon}\gt 1\implies \dfrac{1}{e^{\epsilon}}\lt 1\implies \dfrac{e^{\epsilon}-1}{e^{\epsilon}}\lt e^{\epsilon}-1\implies 1-e^{-\epsilon}\lt e^{\epsilon}-1\implies 3-3e^{-\epsilon}\lt 3e^{\epsilon}-3\implies min(3-3e^{-\epsilon},3e^{\epsilon}-3)=3-3e^{-\epsilon}.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84478/discussion-between-arjun-banerjee-and-hopefully).